# Is “She takes herself to be very beautiful” idiomatic

Tags: phrase-usage

A girl in my school is very arrogant and she feels that she's very beautiful. So someone says:

> Yeah! She takes herself to be very beautiful.

Is the use of "take herself to be" natural?

Comment: We can understand it easily, and the expression, "takes [someone] to be [some quality]," *is* idiomatic in some circumstances, so I'm not sure anyone could say that the example sentence was unnatural. If I heard it, I might think, "Hmm, ... wonder where that person is from."

Comment: I find the sentence to be quite natural. I take it that some other people would agree.

Comment: @LorelC. Is it wrong? You said you'd wonder where that person was from...

Comment: @It's about English: It sounds slightly unusual to me, and I don't think people *in my region* use that expression very often. But a related statement, "Everybody *takes him to be* an expert," sounds perfectly normal to me. So it may be a regional thing. I am pretty sure that your sentence is *not incorrect*.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not natural. An idiomatic speaker might say

> considers herself beautiful

a neutral statement

> thinks herself beautiful

a neutral statement

> deems herself beautiful

perhaps implying doubt on that judgment

> presumes herself beautiful

expressing doubt on that judgment.

Comment: I wouldn't say any are neutral, they all express a little insult.Well in the UK they do.

Comment: So I'm a bit confused. There are like 2 suggestions.  So is it natural?

Comment: I generally agree with Jeff Morrow here, though I would concede that "considers" and "thinks" are *potentially* neutral. It depends on context. @It'saboutEnglish, the phrasing you suggest in your question is not something one would expect a native speaker to say. It is not natural, though any native speaker would understand what it means - though possibly with some doubt, and recognising that the speaker is probably not a native speaker of English.

Answer (score 0):

Comment moved to answer:
It's not incorrect, but given the context of the sentence (which sounds like classmates gossiping about another student) I'd be surprised to hear it. It sounds very formal to me. Also I think the reflexive pronoun makes it more unusual than the example that Lorel C gives above in the comments.

Other options: 
In the context as I understand it, which is slightly derogatory, I'd expect to hear something like "**She thinks she's so** [pretty/fancy/smart/adj]." The addition of the "so" changes this from a neutral statement to one that casts doubt on the person's opinion.

A slang version of this idea that I think is still fairly common, at least in the US, is "She thinks she's all that." https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=all%20that